# How does Django execute the SQL statement and return to queryset？

Tags: mysql, django

```
select * from user_fresher where name in
       (select name from user_fresher group by name having count(name)>1) and 
        status_id=0 ORDER BY name;
```

I want to execute this statement in Django and return a queryset object , because I need to use it as a filter in admin Page.

Executing SQL statements directly doesn't seem to get the results I want, and I've checked the official documentation and I haven't found a good solution.

Can you help me solve this problem? Or can I use ORM to achieve the purpose of this SQL statement?（I want to find out a duplicate value in a field.）

Comment: Can you post your SQL Statement you are running to get the result you are getting?

Comment: If you're having trouble, you should post the code you used and the results you got. However there doesn't seem to be any reason to use raw SQL for a query like this; it should be a simple filter on an annotation. But for us to help you properly you need to post your models.

Answer (score 0):

[Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/),
The raw() manager method takes a raw SQL query, executes it, and returns a 'django.db.models.query.RawQuerySet' instance.

```
rawQuerySet = Model.objects.raw(SQL)
```

And you can get the QuerySet object from RawQuerySet object.

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(pk__in=[x.pk for x in rawQueryset])
```

This is a tedious process, and I am looking forward to better answers.